# Email notifications based on comments?

Tags: support, comments

If someone comments that they need a code sample or they asked a question and **then I do**, how do they get notified that the stuff has been posted and they should go back and continue the answer?

If this feature is available and it's off by default and people don't know of its existence, that would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

They get notified through their envelop if you reply using the `@TheirName: Message` format.

Comment: Where is this kind of information mentioned?

Comment: @Tony: nowhere (except the blog and posts in here on meta)

Comment: Quick question: is the semicolon required after `@TheirName`?

Comment: @MaximZaslavsky: no, and it suffices to use the first three letters. But if e.g. two Maxims where there, one would have to use enough letters to uniquely identify the correct user. And omit all spaces!

Comment: @Tob that's what I thought - just making sure! :)

Comment: @Tony: *[How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)*